# C++ Builder and TeeChart > how to fix the graph range even when the axis is set to left or right side

Tags: c++builder, teechart

My environment:

```
RadStudio 10.2 Tokyo
```

What I would like to do is:

- fix the graph range

When I change the side of the axis from left to right, the graph range is changed by hiding/showing the axis title and labels.

For example

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include <DateUtils.hpp>
#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    addDummyDate();
}

void __fastcall TForm1::addDummyDate()
{
    Chart1->Series[0]->XValues->DateTime = true;
    Chart1->BottomAxis->DateTimeFormat = L"nn:ss";

    TDateTime dt;

    dt = Now();

    double yval;
    for (int idx=0; idx < 10; idx++) {
        yval = (1+ idx) % 2;
        Series1->AddXY(dt, yval, "", clRed);
        dt = IncSecond(dt, 1);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (Button1->Tag == 0) {
        Button1->Tag = 1;
        Chart1->Series[0]->VertAxis = aRightAxis;
    } else {
        Button1->Tag = 0;
        Chart1->Series[0]->VertAxis = aLeftAxis;
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- when the axis is at the left handed side

  - [image]
- when the axis is at the right handed side

  - [image]

I searched the internet (and steema documents), but I haven't found the solution yet.

My goals is:
can print the graph at the same location whatever the configuration is.

Comment: Can you put the chart in a panel and reposition the chart when swapping sides?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's possible. However, in that case, I have to calculate the position by myself. I was searching a simple way to do the purpose, but eventually I may do the way you mentioned.

Comment: I have implemented the code to fix the left position at https://qiita.com/7of9/items/95311f1a7f06f43eec97

Comment: Looks good! Better than my idea.